# how to reduce the execution time of grid in selenium

Tags: selenium, grid

I am using 4 nodes, thread =14 takes - 1hour 14 minutes(execution time)

increasing thread count does'nt reduces time or decreasing thread count does'nt reduces time .

I want to reduce time to half an hour. but its not happening.
I am having 185 test cases.
 please provide any suggestion on how to reduce  time.
I am using chrome browser only

Comment: plz provide some more info, how many browsers per node? max sessions per node? no of parallel browsers mentioned in testng? etc

Comment: max browsers are 5 in each node. max session not added while creating node. its by default 5.  parallel browser -I am only running testcases in chrome ,no other browsers are used